# How to update variable inside a parameter file

Tags: etl, informatica, informatica-powercenter

lets say i have a parameter file

```
[Global]
$$param1=x
$$param2=r
$$param3=t
$$param4=h
$$param5=j
$$Counter=0
```

what i want is whenever i run the session the parameter file updates and $Counter variable increments by 1
so that it be like this after the first run

```
[Global]
$$param1=x
$$param2=r
$$param3=t
$$param4=h
$$param5=j
$$Counter=1
```

and so on
i searched alot but i didn't see clear answers for that
some answers say i should use shell scripting but i didn't know how to use it in my case

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to update these kind of param files.

1. Use a scheduler like Oracle DAC/Automic/ControlM/Cybermation. They have a mechanism to update parameters daily. This is easy but if you are not willing to use a new tool, pls use option 2 or 3.
2. Create a shell script which will update this param file in the beginning of the infa flow. You can create a CMD task or you can use it as pre session command task to the very first session of workflow.
   Shell script will be like

```
#!/bin/bash

param1=$1
param2=$2
param3=$3

sed -i -e "s/\(param1=\).*/\1$1/" \
-e "s/\(param2=\).*/\1$2/" \
-e "s/\(param3=\).*/\1$3/" global.prm

awk -i inplace -F"=" 'BEGIN{OFS=FS} $1=="Counter"{$2=$2+1}1' global.prm
```

Please test the script before using it.

3. Use an informatica mapping to update the global param file. Create a mapping which will update this file and update the counter as well. And then use it to create a workflow and make sure it runs as first workflow of your chain of workflows.